# How to run two cameras in ROS at different times?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run two cameras on one single board computer with ROS and OpenCV, but I do not want to run the cameras at the same time. I want to run camera A until a specific moment then turn camera A off and turn camera B on; then B off and A on, and so on...

I am not sure how to do this effectively or at all really. I understand how to start up both cameras with a launch file or turn them off and on manually, but I want to do this automatically as certain parameters are met. Any ideas or advice?

Thanks

- Ralff

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127906/how-to-run-two-cameras-in-ros-at-different-times?/) by [Ralff](https://answers.ros.org/users/11841/ralff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2014-02-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably a good use case for the capabilities server: http://wiki.ros.org/capabilities ( [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/capabilities/Tutorials/CapabilityDemo) )

The capabilities server allows you to declare launch files as capabilities, and then bring them up and down using ROS service calls.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ralff](https://answers.ros.org/users/11841/ralff/) on 2014-02-10**:
Thanks. I will read up on capabilities to see if that will work.

By the way, one reason I do not want to run two cameras simultaneously is that I receive an error for exceeding the bus capacity. It also seems more efficient to only run the camera that is being used.

**Comment by [Ralff](https://answers.ros.org/users/11841/ralff/) on 2014-09-03**:
I was never able to get the capabilities server working, but I found a way to control two cameras by writing a program to kill and restart the nodes using fork. This wasn't the cleanest method for doing this, but it worked fine for my application.